# share app.config with different projects

Tags: c#

I have multiple projects in my solution. Across all the projects I have app.config file with all the config sections same for them. How can I share the config file in different projects but when I change the main one, the changes should be replicated across other app config files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `app.config` in a shared location (within the project directory, not on a network drive or something like that) and use the `Add As Link` feature in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: perfect it works. I did see this work around in other posts, but I was wondering if we change the config file at one location, do the changes get carry forwarded to other places in the solution.

Comment: Yes. It references the file, it doesn't copy it. So there is only a single copy of the file.